# forward looking rolling window in pandas - ragged index

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, time-series

hope someone can help me here
I am trying to create a forward rolling window on a ragged time index.
Pandas complains about monotonicity - which is obviously respected in my index.
The normal backward window works just fine.

[EDIT] The reverse time index does not pass is_monotonic. So I guess it requires a monotonic *rising* index and not just monotonic index.

Anyone has a better alternative please
thanks a lot!

```
In [352] tmp[::-1]
Out[352]: 
stamp
2018-04-23 06:45:16.920   -0.11
2018-04-23 06:45:16.919   -0.03
2018-04-23 06:45:16.918   -0.01
2018-04-23 06:45:16.917   -0.02
2018-04-23 06:45:16.916    0.03
2018-04-23 06:45:16.914    0.03
2018-04-23 06:45:16.911    0.03
2018-04-23 06:45:16.910    0.06
2018-04-23 06:45:16.909    0.09
2018-04-23 06:45:16.908    0.08
2018-04-23 06:45:16.907    0.18
2018-04-23 06:45:16.906    0.28
2018-04-23 06:45:16.905    0.28
2018-04-23 06:45:16.904    0.02
2018-04-23 06:45:16.903    0.09
2018-04-23 06:45:16.902    0.09
2018-04-23 06:45:16.901    0.09
2018-04-23 06:45:16.900    0.09
2018-04-23 06:45:16.899   -0.24
2018-04-23 06:45:16.898   -0.22
2018-04-23 06:45:16.894   -0.22
2018-04-23 06:45:16.799   -0.21
2018-04-23 06:45:16.798   -0.19
2018-04-23 06:45:16.797   -0.21
2018-04-23 06:45:15.057   -0.13
2018-04-23 06:45:15.056   -0.16
2018-04-23 06:45:13.382   -0.04
2018-04-23 06:45:13.381   -0.02
2018-04-23 06:45:13.380   -0.05
2018-04-23 06:45:13.379   -0.08
Name: d66, dtype: float64

In [353]: tmp[::-1].rolling('20L')
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-355-74bdfcdfbbd1>", line 1, in <module>
    tmp[::-1].rolling('20L')

  File "C:\Users\luigi\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py", line 7067, in rolling
    on=on, axis=axis, closed=closed)

  File "C:\Users\luigi\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\window.py", line 2069, in rolling
    return Rolling(obj, **kwds)

  File "C:\Users\luigi\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\window.py", line 86, in __init__
    self.validate()

  File "C:\Users\luigi\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\window.py", line 1104, in validate
    self._validate_monotonic()

  File "C:\Users\luigi\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\window.py", line 1136, in _validate_monotonic
    "monotonic".format(formatted))

ValueError: index must be monotonic

In [356]: tmp.index.is_monotonic
Out[356]: True

In [357]: tmp[::-1].index.is_monotonic
Out[357]: False

In [358]: tmp[::-1].index.is_monotonic_decreasing
Out[358]: True
```

Comment: Take a look at [this issue](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/19248) on github, it seems that there is no support for decreasing monotonic indices yet

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just in case you are still looking for a solution. with **reindex()** and the help of an extra column, the rolling functions with ragged forward-looking window should be doable.

```
import pandas as pd
from io import StringIO

str = """dtime          value
2018-04-23 06:45:16.920   -0.11
2018-04-23 06:45:16.919   -0.03
2018-04-23 06:45:16.918   -0.01
2018-04-23 06:45:16.917   -0.02
2018-04-23 06:45:16.916    0.03
2018-04-23 06:45:16.914    0.03
2018-04-23 06:45:16.911    0.03
2018-04-23 06:45:16.910    0.06
2018-04-23 06:45:16.909    0.09
2018-04-23 06:45:16.908    0.08
2018-04-23 06:45:16.907    0.18
2018-04-23 06:45:16.906    0.28
2018-04-23 06:45:16.905    0.28
2018-04-23 06:45:16.904    0.02
2018-04-23 06:45:16.903    0.09
2018-04-23 06:45:16.902    0.09
2018-04-23 06:45:16.901    0.09
2018-04-23 06:45:16.900    0.09
2018-04-23 06:45:16.899   -0.24
2018-04-23 06:45:16.898   -0.22
2018-04-23 06:45:16.894   -0.22
2018-04-23 06:45:16.799   -0.21
2018-04-23 06:45:16.798   -0.19
2018-04-23 06:45:16.797   -0.21
2018-04-23 06:45:15.057   -0.13
2018-04-23 06:45:15.056   -0.16
2018-04-23 06:45:13.382   -0.04
2018-04-23 06:45:13.381   -0.02
2018-04-23 06:45:13.380   -0.05
2018-04-23 06:45:13.379   -0.08
"""

## read the data tmp[::-1]
df = pd.read_table(StringIO(str), sep="\s\s+", engine="python", index_col=["dtime"], parse_dates=['dtime'])

## reverse the data to its original order
df = df[::-1]   

## setup the offset, i.e. 10ms
offset = '10ms'

# create a new column with values as index datetime plus the window timedelta 10ms
df['dt_new'] = df.index + pd.Timedelta(offset)

# use df.index and this new column to form the new index(remove duplicates and sort the list)
idx = sorted(set([*df.index.tolist(), *df.dt_new.tolist()]))

# reindex the original dataframe and calculate the backward rolling sum
df1 = df.reindex(idx).fillna(value={'value':0}).value.rolling(offset, closed='left').sum().to_frame()

# make a LEFt join to the original dataframe. `value_y` should be the forward rolling sum
df.merge(df1, left_on='dt_new', right_index=True, how='left')
#                         value_x                  dt_new  value_y
#dtime                                                            
#2018-04-23 06:45:13.379    -0.08 2018-04-23 06:45:13.389    -0.19
#2018-04-23 06:45:13.380    -0.05 2018-04-23 06:45:13.390    -0.11
#2018-04-23 06:45:13.381    -0.02 2018-04-23 06:45:13.391    -0.06
#2018-04-23 06:45:13.382    -0.04 2018-04-23 06:45:13.392    -0.04
#2018-04-23 06:45:15.056    -0.16 2018-04-23 06:45:15.066    -0.29
#2018-04-23 06:45:15.057    -0.13 2018-04-23 06:45:15.067    -0.13
#2018-04-23 06:45:16.797    -0.21 2018-04-23 06:45:16.807    -0.61
#2018-04-23 06:45:16.798    -0.19 2018-04-23 06:45:16.808    -0.40
#2018-04-23 06:45:16.799    -0.21 2018-04-23 06:45:16.809    -0.21
#2018-04-23 06:45:16.894    -0.22 2018-04-23 06:45:16.904    -0.32
#2018-04-23 06:45:16.898    -0.22 2018-04-23 06:45:16.908     0.66
#2018-04-23 06:45:16.899    -0.24 2018-04-23 06:45:16.909     0.96
#2018-04-23 06:45:16.900     0.09 2018-04-23 06:45:16.910     1.29
#2018-04-23 06:45:16.901     0.09 2018-04-23 06:45:16.911     1.26
#2018-04-23 06:45:16.902     0.09 2018-04-23 06:45:16.912     1.20
#2018-04-23 06:45:16.903     0.09 2018-04-23 06:45:16.913     1.11
#2018-04-23 06:45:16.904     0.02 2018-04-23 06:45:16.914     1.02
#2018-04-23 06:45:16.905     0.28 2018-04-23 06:45:16.915     1.03
#2018-04-23 06:45:16.906     0.28 2018-04-23 06:45:16.916     0.75
#2018-04-23 06:45:16.907     0.18 2018-04-23 06:45:16.917     0.50
#2018-04-23 06:45:16.908     0.08 2018-04-23 06:45:16.918     0.30
#2018-04-23 06:45:16.909     0.09 2018-04-23 06:45:16.919     0.21
#2018-04-23 06:45:16.910     0.06 2018-04-23 06:45:16.920     0.09
#2018-04-23 06:45:16.911     0.03 2018-04-23 06:45:16.921    -0.08
#2018-04-23 06:45:16.914     0.03 2018-04-23 06:45:16.924    -0.11
#2018-04-23 06:45:16.916     0.03 2018-04-23 06:45:16.926    -0.14
#2018-04-23 06:45:16.917    -0.02 2018-04-23 06:45:16.927    -0.17
#2018-04-23 06:45:16.918    -0.01 2018-04-23 06:45:16.928    -0.15
#2018-04-23 06:45:16.919    -0.03 2018-04-23 06:45:16.929    -0.14
#2018-04-23 06:45:16.920    -0.11 2018-04-23 06:45:16.930    -0.11
```

**Some Notes:**

1. The results might vary based on how you define and select the `closed` option when the size of the rolling window is an `offset`. By default `closed` is set to `right`. If shifting 'offset' is the method applied(as in this example), the rolling aggregation must be calculated with `closed` = `left`. (you might have different design though). When the window size is a fixed number, the deault `closed` is 'both'.
2. The index (`dtime` field) should not contain duplicates, if not, `idx` should be de-duplicated based on two fields (dtime, value).

**Potential issues:**

1. The reindex() could potentially double the number of rows at the worst scenario.
2. Join dataframes by using a datetime field, this might not work on every system if the datetimes are saved as floating number.

Comment: great answer jxc!